# How to block broadcast packets EXITING a single switchport

Tags: broadcast, storm-control

I have a couple cheap  external wireless APs that like to reboot themselves constantly if they get even a few broadcast packets (i am ~90% certain this is the cause, after some testing with wireshark and cisco storm-control).

I have already replaced one of the APs with a super nice Cisco AP that works like a champ, but I can't replace the other one yet.  For the time being, i need to reliably block ALL broadcast packets EXITING a single switchport (that the AP is connected to) on a Catalyst 2960-x

From what I understand, Cisco Storm-Control works on switch port ingress, and rather than 'throttling' based on the set threshold (% or pps), it just starts blocking packets until the packets drop below the threshold.

I also understand that 'switchport block unicast/multicast' works on switchport egress, and unfortunately there is no 'switchport block broadcast' command.

So far I have had some success if I use storm-control to completely block broadcast packets coming in on the uplink port, but of course this causes problems for anything on the uplink side trying to communicate with the devices connected to the switch, and also initial connectivity to the AP after a reboot (i have to temporarily turn off storm-control in order to re-connect to the AP web interface after the AP reboots, since my workstation is on the uplink side of the switch)

Any suggestions?

I thought perhaps just putting another small cisco switch in between the 2960-x and the AP, and setting IT to block all ingress broadcast packets  on the uplink port via storm-control, but I am hoping there is another way.

Comment: Ethernet IP networks require broadcasts to function. Blocking all broadcasts going out a switch port will isolate anything on the outside of the switch port. You can reduce the broadcast domain by segmenting into VLANs.

Comment: The current LAN broadcast domain is fine.. but these APs are just very sensitive to even small amounts of broadcast traffic.  I had thought about creating a dedicated VLAN for this AP, but considering the effort needed to trunk and route it across the network, i hoped there might be an alternative, since this AP will eventually be replaced as well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have analysed the traffic already with wireshark you can probably create a L2 ACL outbound on the cisco switch. Be sure to not block ARP traffic (also Broadcast) else you will not be able to use IPv4!